# Correlational statistics? Which should I use?

Tags: factor-analysis, survey

I am conducting a correlational study to determine if there is a relationship between servant leadership characteristics in building principals and levels of teacher self-efficacy as measures by the Teacher's Sense of Efficacy Scale.  I thought about regression analysis, but am not sure if I should use ANOVA or Pearson's.  The survey instrument for servant leadership will be administered to all personnel in the building to determine the level of servant leadership present and the Efficacy Scale will be administered to teachers in the building to determine of servant leadership characteristics heighten levels of efficacy in the classroom.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is the servant leadership survey instrument given to teachers? Who fills this out and what does it evaluate?

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that measures of both the exposure (leadership characteristics) and outcome (teacher self-efficacy) are ordinally scaled variables. For instance, teacher efficacy may be evaluated on a 4-point Likert scale.

With Pearson's chi-square test for contingency tables, the null hypothesis is stated that for any reported leadership level, the proportions of self-efficacy in teaching are exactly the same. We will reject the null hypothesis if any proportion of efficacy responses in any leadership evaluation level is different than any other efficacy response. This makes reporting the results of a significant analysis difficult. You might observe the "worst" leadership responders having bimodal proportions (50% least efficacious, 50% most efficacious) whereas "best" leadership responders are moderate (25% all efficacy). In this case, there is no difference in aggregate teaching levels (same mean, consistent median, just a little more diverse).

If we're interested in a *trend* in that data, one option is to use linear regression with numerically coded contingency levels. This exploits the ordering to determine if there's a first order trend in the numeric data. If we find the inference on the slope parameter from a linear regression model is significant, then we can report the results of a significant analysis as, "on average, individuals with better evaluations of leadership also self-reported better teaching efficacy (p value)". This is the same as doing an ANOVA. It also has more power because it uses ordering.

When I analyze this type of data, I like treating ordinal variables as continuous because it allows me to exploit their ordered nature to develop better statistical results.